# How to pass Props into React Router 6 so it can be accessed in mapStateToProps(state,ownProps)?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using redux for one of my component. In mapStateToProps I like to use the  id of the URL Params, but in no ways I am able to get the id of the url in that function.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  **const recId = ownProps.id;**
  const reconciliationRule =
    recId && state.reconciliationRules.length > 0
      ? getReconciliationById(state.reconciliationRules, recId)
      : newReconciliationRule;
  return {
    reconciliationRule,
    reconciliationRules: state.reconciliationRules,
  };
```

My route.js looks like below

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "app",
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "dashboard", element: <DashboardComponent /> },
      { path: "reconciliations", element: <ReconciliationComponent /> },
      ***{ path: "reconciliationRule/:id", element: <RulesComponent /> },***
      { path: "help", element: <HelpComponent /> },
      { path: "reports", element: <ReportComponent /> },
      { path: "settings", element: <SettingsComponent /> },
      { path: "billing", element: <BillingComponent /> },
      { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
    ],
  }
]
```

See if you see I want to send { path: "reconciliationRule/:id", element:  } into RulesComponent

Static props I can send easily e.g.

```
{ path: "reconciliationRule/:id", element: <RulesComponent staticId={1}/> }
```

I can access this in mapStateToProps, but question is how to pass an ID of URL in react-router-dom.

Tried lot of permutation and combination but unable to solve it.

Don't want to switch to rr5 or rr4 where I can do this using rendering, but I need this to be done rr6.

Any help in this regards will be appreciated.

Comment: you can curried function to pass an id in the presentational component in useEffect.

Comment: so you are telling that you cant access `:id` of your URL in props?

Comment: try props.match.params.id